# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth(...).setPersistence(...).signInWithPopup is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I seem to be having an issue when trying to set the persistence of the Firebase Auth session, I have been coming back and forward, trying to google search the issue but cannot seem to find an issue.

Below is my HTML and Javascript code, I am also using jQuery but that should not have an impact I believe.

**HTML Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Firebase stuff -->
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <title>Loading EasiChurch...</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="stream.js"></script>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span id="sitetitle"></span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Locations</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownId">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Site Configuration</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stream Configuration</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Booking Configuration</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Donations Configuration</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Sign Out</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<!--<div id="div_logged_in">
    <h1>Welcome <span id="username"></span>!</h1>
</div>
-->
<div id="div_not_logged_in">
    <center>>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3 class="display-4"><span id="sitetitle">Sitetitle</span></h3>
            <p class="lead">Please Sign In using your Google Account below...</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <center><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" onclick="googleSignin()" role="button">Sign in with Google.</a></center>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>

<body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<style>
    .jumbotron {
        padding-right: 9px;
        margin-top: 5%;
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 3%;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

console.log("Ready to go! Firebase Domain: " + firebaseConfig.authDomain)

// Session id is set before anything else, this is exicting
const sessionid = Math.random(); // changes per refresh, not really an issue tbh

// Initialise span variables that will change when we load firebase....
var loggedin = false;
var sitetitle;
var sitedescription;
var siteid;
var locations = {
    core: "Hutt Valley",
    sub1: "Hutt Valley",
    sub2: "Hutt Valley",
    sub3: "Hutt Valley",
    sub4: "Hutt Valley",
};

// NOTE NEED TO USE DOM on load!!!
$('#div_logged_in').hide();
$('#div_not_logged_in').show();

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

function googleSignin() {
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)

    .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        console.log("Google Array Table below -><-")
        console.log(token);
        console.log(user);
        var name = user.displayName;
        $('#div_logged_in').show();
        $('#div_not_logged_in').hide();
        welcomeMessage(user.displayName);
        setupHTML(name);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
    });
}

function googleSignout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut()

    .then(function() {
        console.log('Signout Succesfull')
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Signout Failed')
    });
}



function welcomeMessage(user) {
    alert("Welcome " + user + "!")
}

// Setup HTML here...

function setupHTML(username) {
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = username;
}
```

Comment: [`setPersistence()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence) returns a promise, not the auth instance. See the examples in the documentation

Comment: I would also suggest you use the same version of all Firebase script files. Right now you have a mix of `7.15.0` and `7.14.5`